# Video editing on Windows Mobile

Tags: video, editing, windows-mobile

Does anyone know of any video editing software that works on Windows Mobile?

Comment: smartphone questions are generally offtopic on Super User.  try asking on [PhoneHow](http://phonehow.com/).

Comment: @quack quixote: point taken, however my phone is an order of magnitude faster than my first computer - I couldn't edit video on that either ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are none, period. Windows Mobile 6.5 and below do not have robust enough hardware acceleration APIs to allow an effective video editing solution to surface.

Comment: That's a bit disappointing.  There are some fairly grunty Windows Mobile phones out there.